# NameError: name 'u1' is not defined

Tags: django-models, python-2.7

I am trying to follow django tutorial but with my own task.

Models.py file looks like

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()
    reg_date = models.DateField()
class Question(models.Model):
    head = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateField()
class Answer(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateField()
    validity = models.BooleanField()
```

I made "python manage.py shell" and wrote something like:

```
>>> u1 = User(nickname='Alex', password='123', email='alex@mail.ru', reg_date='2013-01-07')
>>> u1.save()
>>> u2 = User(nickname='Kate', password='abcde', email='kitten@mail.ru', reg_date='2012-12-15')
>>> u2.save()
```

User_list gave me

```
[<User: User object>, <User: User object>]
```

But then I made a quit and did some changes in the code. After this I cannot make u1.delete() or u2.delete() because it tells NameError: name 'u1' is not defined, but still shows me list of two users there. I can also create new u1 and u2 and delete them. How can I apply to those previous users now to clear database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delete **all** User rows:

```
User.objects.all().delete()
```

If you want to find and delete the two your code created:

```
User.objects.get(nickname='Alex').delete()
User.objects.get(nickname='Kate').delete()
```